# CDI/WELD can a custom qualifier work in combination with the @Named annotation?

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, cdi, weld

While having a custom qualifier for CDI support as followed:

```java
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface QualifiedFooBean {
}
```

```java
@QualifiedFooBean
public class FooBean implements ImplFooBean {
}
```

```java
public interface ImplFooBean {
}
```

I would like to bind FooBean #{fooBean} directly without requiring a wrapper or processor (seen from this [example](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/cdi-inject.html)). The annotation "Named" (in class FooBean) seems not to work for my class layout.

My solution (without wrapper) which I'm wondering why it's not working and invoking: Target Unreachable, identifier 'fooBean' resolved to null

```java
@Named
@QualifiedFooBean
public class FooBean implements ImplFooBean {
}
```

Has anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wrapper is not needed. My solution is perfectly valid. It's also allowed to add Named in combination of a custom qualifier (in my case QualifiedFooBean). I had to just create an empty **beans.xml** file in **WEB-INF** folder in order to get CDI to work. Anyhow The question itself explains how custom qualifiers can work. You can also prefill beans.xml with following content:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

It will serve as a skeleton for future use, if you need to configure more fancy stuff with CDI.

Comment: CDI wasn't activated @maglebolia so why did you said the wrapper solution was working for you. It's better to give effective information when asking help.

Comment: This was due to my confidence of the seen examples on the net always with a wrapper, I just took it for granted that it'll work. But I get the point of actually explaning my situation and not making assumptions. Thank you anyway for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `@Named` to your bean should work : it works for me.

In Fact @Named is a qualifier, when JSF resolve the Bean for displaying it does a lokup based on `@Named` qualifier. In CDI a bean is found if the lookup side (i.e. Injection point) ask for a subset of its Qualifier.

For instance a bean qualified like that :

```
@QualifiedFooBean
@SecondQualifier
public class FooBean {}
```

Will be found (if there is no ambiguous resolution) by

```
@Inject
@SecondQualifier
FooBean bean;
```

or even :

```
@Inject
FooBean bean;
```

But not by

```
@Inject
@SecondQualifier
@ThirdQualifier
FooBean bean;
```

So you can add the `@Named` qualifier and let CDI resolution engine do its job.

Comment: I've updated my question, to reflect my issue better. @Antoine: I had ambiguous warnings before creating the custom qualifier. They are gone... combination of Named and Default works but it seems to fail when it's actually a costum qualifier Named + QualifiedFooBean

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Have you tried to put your bean in RequestScope (like that it's dependent and is created each time requested)